# Convert json dict to row in pandas df

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have pulled JSON data from a url. The result is a dictionary. How can I transform this dictionary so that each key is a column, and the timestamp is the index for each row- where the dict `values` correspond to the row entries each time the url is called?

Here is the data:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.blockchain.info/stats') as url:
    block_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

# Convert to Pandas
block_df = pd.DataFrame(block_data)
```

I tried:

```
block_df = pd.DataFrame(block_data)
block_df = pd.DataFrame(block_data, index = 'timestamp')
block_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(block_data)
block_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(block_data, orient = 'columns')
```

But all attempts give different errors:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

and

> TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'timestamp' was passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `block_data` in a list

```
pd.DataFrame([block_data]).set_index('timestamp')

               blocks_size    difficulty  estimated_btc_sent  estimated_transaction_volume_usd     hash_rate  market_price_usd  miners_revenue_btc  miners_revenue_usd  minutes_between_blocks  n_blocks_mined  n_blocks_total   n_btc_mined    n_tx  nextretarget   total_btc_sent  total_fees_btc           totalbc  trade_volume_btc  trade_volume_usd
timestamp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
1504121943000    167692649  888171856257      24674767461479                      1.130867e+09  7.505715e+09           4583.09                2540         11645247.85                    7.92             170          482689  212500000000  281222        483839  174598204968248     41591624963  1653361250000000          43508.93      1.994054e+08
```

---

With `datetime` index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([block_data]).set_index('timestamp')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')
df

                     blocks_size    difficulty  estimated_btc_sent  estimated_transaction_volume_usd     hash_rate  market_price_usd  miners_revenue_btc  miners_revenue_usd  minutes_between_blocks  n_blocks_mined  n_blocks_total   n_btc_mined    n_tx  nextretarget   total_btc_sent  total_fees_btc           totalbc  trade_volume_btc  trade_volume_usd
timestamp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
2017-08-30 19:39:03    167692649  888171856257      24674767461479                      1.130867e+09  7.505715e+09           4583.09                2540         11645247.85                    7.92             170          482689  212500000000  281222        483839  174598204968248     41591624963  1653361250000000          43508.93      1.994054e+08
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. One more question- how can I convert the unix timstamp index to datetime after it has been set?